# Structs in C++ sorting with qsort

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

Ok so I have this code:

```
struct person
{
    char *firstname, *lastname;
    int age
};
```

What should I do to read a specified number of persons then sort them by their age with qsort?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/. There you have an example with `int`s. You just have to adapt the `compare` for your struct...

Comment: I'm stuck at reading more persons based on this struct.

Comment: Stuck how? What have you done so far? What errors do you get? This is a place to ask specific questions about specific problems, not get your research/learning/work done for you.

Comment: In this struct i scan person age with scanf, in a for loop for reading n persons.I don't know how to compare ages between people i read in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, since the question is marked C++, you should use std::sort. That algorithm is faster than ANSI C qsort.

Just read the persons into an STL container, e.g. std::vector. Then define a sorting criterion, basically the equivalent of operator < (less-than), for the person struct. Then just call std::sort, that is it!

Use Josuttis book about C++ standard library (best reference) or use e.g.
an online reference like [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: I'm not so advanced into c++, and my teacher didn't specified in class anything about std, can you give me a more detailed example?

Comment: No, you have to do some work yourself. Google it, or search in Stack Overflow for similar questions.